# How to Skip a step in user journey of Azure B2C Custom policy based on an input query parameter of the request

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have an input claim as below
`<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isAccessFlow"  PartnerClaimType="access_flow" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:access_flow}"/>`

under `<TechnicalProfile Id="Google-OAUTH">`

Based on this value i want to skip the MFA orchesration step in user journey.To do that i need to get the value form output claim. So how can i pass the value from input claim into output claim or how can i directly use input claim in userjourney to stop the step.

My user journey orchestration step are below

```
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signinandsignupwithpassword">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AD" />
          <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ADFSExchange" />
          <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="MicrosoftExchange" />
           <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="ADFSExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ADFS-SAML2" />
          <ClaimsExchange Id="MicrosoftExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MSA-OIDC" />
          <ClaimsExchange Id="AD" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="OIDC-AD" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId). 
          This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
          using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
             from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
             (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
   <!-- Phone verification: If MFA is not required, the next three steps (#5-#7) should be removed.
             This step checks whether there's a phone number on record,  for the user. If found, then the user is challenged to verify it. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isActiveMFASession</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>requiresMFA</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
           <!--  <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isAccessFlow</Value>
               <Value>true</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition> -->
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PhoneFactor-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

The commented part in orchestration step 6 is what i am trying to achieve but failing
I'm new to custom policies, so please correct me if i am doing it a wrong way.

Comment: Can you post the first 2 steps of your user journey?

Comment: @JasSuri  , Edited my question with orchestration steps till MFA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself.
We can also use the claim resolver in Output claim as below
 `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isAccessFlow" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:access_flow}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>`

Settings:

- The **IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling** metadata must be set to
  true.
- The input or output claims attribute **AlwaysUseDefaultValue**
  must be set to true.

These setting i missed earlier and had to struggle. After adding these the below precondition works as expected.

```
           <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isAccessFlow</Value>
               <Value>true</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
```

Comment: That’s right. An input claim in an oauth technical profile will just send it as a query parameter to google. But not output anything to the global claim bag once complete for use later.

Comment: The guidance on the flags to use is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview